# PHP Insert array into MySQL database get data from checkbox

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

HTML Input

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="que[10][1]">
<input type="checkbox" value="2" name="que[10][2]">
<input type="checkbox" value="3" name="que[10][3]">
...
<input type="checkbox" value="40" name="que[10][40]">
```

PHP submit

```
$submit = $_POST["que"];
```

I have the following array I want to store in my database :

> 

```
Array
(
    [10] => Array
        (
            [0] => 26
            [1] => 27
            [2] => 28
            [3] => 29
            [4] => 30
            [5] => 31
        )

)
```

How can I convert to insert statement output following as below :

```
INSERT INTO `tb_answers` (`question_id`, `answer`) VALUES(10,26),(10,27),(10,28),(10,29),(10,30);
```

Here is my code :

```
$submit = $_POST['que'];

$all_values = [];

$sql_submit_form = "INSERT INTO `tb_answers` (`question_id`, `answer`) VALUES";

foreach ($submit as $question_id => $choise) {
   
    $row_values = [];
    foreach ($choise as $choise_data => $s_value) { 
        $row_values[] = "'" . $question_id . "'"; // question_id
        $row_values[] = "'" . $s_value . "'"; // answer

    }
    $all_values[] = '(' . implode(',', $row_values) . ')';
}
$sql_submit_form .= implode(',', $all_values);

echo $sql_submit_form;
```

Output :

```
INSERT INTO `tb_answers` (`question_id`, `answer`) VALUES('10','27','10','28','10','29','10','30','10','31','10','32')
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: What's your question about the given code? Looks like you build the query the wrong way. Also, be warned that the given way of building a query is widely open for SQL injection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to clean up what you already have. There's also no need to inject raw data into your SQL code, that only makes code harder to maintain (apart from insecure):

```
$params = $clauses = [];
foreach ($submit as $question_id => $choices) {
    foreach ($choices as $choice_id) {
        $clauses[] = '(?, ?)';
        $params[] = $question_id;
        $params[] = $choice_id;
    }
}
$sql = 'INSERT INTO `tb_answers` (`question_id`, `answer`) VALUES ' . implode(', ', $clauses);
```

Then feed `$params` to a prepared statement and you'll be done.

Comment: Thank you so much.
I tried this code here is output : 
$sql=INSERT INTO `tb_answers` (`question_id`, `answer`) VALUES (10, 29), (10, 30), (10, 31)

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, you construct your SQL query wrong. SQL Injection is a thing, you need to use '?' placeholders if you plan to use this in production environments.
Your desired output can be generated like that:

```
$row_values = [];
foreach ($submit as $question_id => $choise) {
    foreach ($choise as $choise_data => $s_value) {
        $row_values[] = "(". $question_id .",".$s_value . ")";
    }
}
$sql_submit_form .= implode(',', $row_values);
```